# Laravel resource pagination meta data missing

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Recently I have implemented Laravel pagination with resources. But the problem is when I add some custom attributes or wrappers, pagination metadata gets lost. without wrappers or custom attributes, working fine.

*Resource class*

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

*Controller function*

```
public function index()
{
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'true',
            'message'=>'Request successful',
            'result' => UserResource::collection(User::paginate(3))
        ]);
}
```

*Output*

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "message": "Request successful",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "System Admin",
            "email": "admin@abc.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

**^ pagination data missing**

*Expectation*

```
{
  "success": "true",
  "message": "Request successful",
  "result": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "System Admin",
        "email": "admin@abc.com"
      },
      {
        ......
      }
    ],
    "links": {
      "first": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user?page=1",
      "last": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user?page=4",
      "prev": null,
      "next": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user?page=2"
    },
    "meta": {
      "current_page": 1,
      "from": 1,
      "last_page": 4,
      "path": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user",
      "per_page": 3,
      "to": 3,
      "total": 11
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is almost identical to an earlier question. See [my answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77517804/21874832).

Answer (score 13):

I have solved that issue using

```
return response()->json([
       'success' => 'true',
       'message'=>'Request successful',
       'result' => UserResource::collection(User::paginate(3))->response()->getData()
      ]);
```

Answer (score 9):

Very simple solution

```
$data = UserResource::collection(User::paginate(3))->resource;
    
     return response()->json([
               'success' => 'true',
               'message'=>'Request successful',
               'data' => $data
              ]);enter code here
```