# try to get response json ,Laravel Pagination has missing meta and links with API resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jsonresponse

Trying

```
$questions=TheQuestion::paginate(5);
return $this->successResponce(TheQuestionResource::collection($questions),'','');

{
   success: true,data: [{},{},{},{},{}],tag: "",message: ""
}

public function successResponce($data,$tag,$message)
{
      return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $data,
            'tag'=>$tag,
            'message' => $message,
        ]);
}
```

API Resource is working fine but pagination data like current_page,total... is not showing.
But When returning without JSON Response all things are coming

```
$questions=TheQuestion::paginate(5);
return TheQuestionResource::collection($questions);
{
    data: [],
    links: {
        first: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/admin/question/management/show/%7B%7D?page=1",
        last: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/admin/question/management/show/%7B%7D?page=3",
        prev: null,
        next: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/admin/question/management/show/%7B%7D?page=2"
},
    meta: {
        current_page: 1,
        from: 1,
        last_page: 3,
        path: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/admin/question/management/show/%7B%7D",
        per_page: 5,
        to: 5,
        total: 11
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `TheQuestionResource::collection($questions)->get()` ?

Comment: or using `->toArray()` before adding it into the the json array

Comment: Already collection why to use get() and ->toArray() is working fine but not in Response

Comment: Because returning a collection in this way might be the problem, just worth a try

Comment: Running into exact same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: This question is almost identical to an earlier one. See [my answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77517588/21874832).